# Distributing Video on a LAN to alternate Locations - Can the browser detect this?

Tags: hadoop, intranet, lan, nas, san

I'm the administrator for a company intranet and I'd like to start producing videos. However, we have a very small bandwidth tunnel between our locations, and I'd like to avoid hogging it by streaming videos by multiple users.

I'd like to synchronize the files to servers at each of the locations. Then I'd like the browser (or the intranet) to detect which site I'm at. From there, I'd like it to request the video from the closest location.

I've never done this, and was wondering if there is already a solution out there for this. It looks like Hadoop may do this, but I guess I'd like to hear that from someone using it before I commit to learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve exactly what you want, but hadoop does not do what you desire.

Hadoop provides an infrastructure to process large amounts of data (like e.g. log file analysis) in a distributed environment (cluster) but the machines in the cluster are usually connected with high speed communication links (may be even on the same server rack).

So I can answer the last part of your question and tell you that hadoop not a good fit for your type of problem. You might still want to learn what hadoop gives you, so that you may be able to use it in another scenario, though.

You might also want to check out [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) to find an answer to your problem, as it seems you are looking to a more system administrator like answer than a programming one.

[Here are good materials to learn about hadoop](http://www.cloudera.com/developers/learn-hadoop/)